# Simple example to get data from YQL

Tags: java, json, yql, yahoo-weather-api

I want to create a java software to show the forecast of my city. I use YQL of Yahoo.
I surf on the net to find a simple Java class (*.java) example to get those data but I find nothing. I already know Java, JSON, WOEID, YQL, ... .
I have this link to get information about forecast: [link: Yahoo Weather JSON with YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+weather.forecast+where+woeid%3D2502265)
Is there a simple example, please? Can you get a link (or links)?
Thanks! :-)

Comment: Since you already know Java, why don't you write one?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I know Java (it's beautiful!) but I see some tutorial but I can't create a correct class to link at JSON result. Can you help me? Is there a tutorial to know how connect to Yahoo-JSON result? Thanks!